# Select2 auto complete search is not showing data asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

When I type or search anything in select2 textbox so it shows searching and it does not show the data from database.
I had put breakpoint on searchProdauto and when compiler come on it,

searchData action search data successfully but it does not show in select2 textbox..

Here is my Home Controller

```
 // GET: /Common/Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult searchProdauto(string q)
    {
        var searchData = rep.GetAll().Where(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith(q, 

StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(y => 
  y.ProductName).ToList();
        return Json(searchData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`Index.cshtml` view code

```
@using Medi.Modals
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/metro.min.js"></script>
<script   src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/metro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br />
<div class="cell auto-size padding20" style="margin-top:1rem;">
<h2>Select2 Examples</h2>
<h3>Basic</h3>
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
    <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
<br />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
        ajax: {

            url: '@Url.Action("searchProdauto","Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the way you process the result according to the definition of your json objected returned by your controller:

```
public JsonResult searchProdauto(string q)
{
    var searchData = rep.GetAll().Where(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith(q,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(y => y.ProductName).ToList();
    return Json(searchData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It seems that you're trying to return a list of `ProductName`. `Select2` needs and `id` and a `text`.

You could change your code to return a json object with an id:

```
var searchData = rep.GetAll().Where(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith(q, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(f => new
   {
    ProductName = f.ProductName,
    ProductId = f.ProductId
   })
.ToList();

return Json(searchData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

then you have to define a rule to map your properties to Select2 properties:

```
processResults: function (data, search) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                  id: item.ProductId ,
                  text: item.ProductName,
                }
            });
        };
}
```

I guess you have to change `select2` data member as well as you're not passing a `page` to your controller:

```
data: function (params) {
        return {
           q: params.term, // search term
           // page: params.page
        };
},
```

and you might have to add

```
templateResult: function (item) {
    if (item.loading) return item.text;
    return item.text;
},
```

Your final code to create a select2 element should look something like this:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("searchProdauto","Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, 
                    // page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, search) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {
                        id: item.ProductId ,
                        text: item.ProductName,
                      }
                   });
               };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        templateResult: function (item) {
          if (item.loading) return item.text;
          return item.text;
        },      
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,

});
```

if you want to access the data of your selection you can use:

```
var data $('.js-example-data-ajax').select2('data');
```

it should contain an array of values passed in

```
templateResult: function (item) { }
```

so if you want to fetch ProductName of the selected item you should be able to do something like this:

```
$('.js-example-data-ajax').select2('data')[0].ProductName;
```

Comment: Glad I've helped mate. Cheers.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy its working for me .. Can you please tell me that how can I pass its selected TEXT in other action or method when I click on my submit button.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I didn't have the chance to test it but I've tried it using the command line in Chrome using their [sample site](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) and it should work. Give me some feedback on this, please. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand that where to put these line of code.

Comment: Well, at some point you're going to post a form - or use ajax to post a form - with some data. I don't know what you will be doing so that line of code tells you how to fetch the selected element, just before you post the data. The best solution would be to have a viewmodel so that your controller can deserialize the data correctly.